# Visualizing what airlines fly in US Airports

Tags: usa, airports, airlines

I am interested in understanding which US airports have what airlines.  One could visualize this with a spreadsheet:

[image]
​
​

This examples shows that Southwest flies out of Midway but not O'Hare.  Delta flies out of O'Hare and not Midway.  Both fly out of Baltimore.

I am not interested in a global \ US map that shows routes destinations of a particular airline: I am not interested in using this data from the passenger use-case.  **A spreadsheet would be preferable although, I suspect that if the data is out there, it is stored in a RDBMS.**

Wondering if there is clever way to tease this info out of http://openflights.org/

Comment: Parsing Wiki should work.

Comment: I am curious what would be the purpose?  With the modern flight search engines able to search for flights from any airport in the metropolitan area, I don't see a point in this endeavor.

Comment: @JonathenReez: please cite an example of a URL that could be parsed for this data.

Comment: with the US alone having over 15000 airports (and over 42000+ worldwide), and nearly 400 airlines, you are up for a _large_ spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a genuine problem faced by a traveller but some sort of personal data analysis project.

Comment: @pnuts I read it.  I still don't see any point in this.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat
$ awk -F, '$3 == "MDW" {print $1}' routes.dat|sort -u
AF
DL
F9
FL
KL
P1
PD
SY
WN
Y4
```

Comment: I like where this is going!  Data is from openflights.org: if only they had an ODBC connector.  With regard to this data: How can the 2 lists of 1) airports and 2) airlines be created from this programatically?  After these lists are enumerated, they would form the x and y axis as shown in the OP.   A two-dimensional array (i.e. spreadsheet 'skeleton') could be created.

Comment: The programming tasks needed to process the data as you describe are pretty far off topic for this site. In short, Berwyn gave you a way to get the airlines serving a particular airport. You could then repeat the query for other airports of interest and assemble them into a chart as you see fit.

Comment: @gatorback The data is CSV. It effectively already is a spreadsheet, you just need to transform it however you wish